# C# Selenium JS.ExecuteScript output

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

Currently trying to output the page content using js console, the code I used is:

```
string list = js.ExecuteScript("angular.element(document).find('body').scope().$$childTail.list") as String;

Console.WriteLine(list);
```

but it's returning blank, however if I do this manually within the console it outputs:

```
0: {url: example.com, list: 1}
1: {url: example.com, list: 2}
```

etc..

Comment: Add return in front of your script, so ("return angular...

Comment: still returns blank

Comment: Hmm, not really sure why then. Is this website external, if so, please post the url so we can try this.

Comment: Maybe you need to add a wait? It's possible the part of the page that you are querying isn't fully loaded when the JS is being executed.